# PySpark - Filter RDD based on another RDD - broadcast an RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, rdd

I've two RDD:
contents & 
remove

Both are RDDs with multiple words by row. What I want is filter all the words in contents that appear in the remove RDD. I am trying with this:

```
filter = contents.filter(lambda line: line[0] not in remove.collect()).collect()
```

But it gives me this:

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Can't do it using the Filter and the Not In operator?

Thanks!

Comment: Referencing RDD `remove` in a closure will cause such problems. You may want to first collect into a variable and then use that variable in your lambda. `removed = remove.collect()
filter = contents.filter(lambda line: line[0] not in removed).collect()`

Comment: I think my syntax is wrong :(

Comment: Was the answer of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember you cannot broadcast an RDD, it is distributed already. And you prove it.

You need not parallelize the remove list, you may or may not broadcast it. E.g.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10))
remove = [5,6]
broadcast = sc.broadcast(remove)
rdd.filter(lambda x: x not in broadcast.value).collect()
```